# Remove spacing after backslash

Tags: spacing, symbols, syntax

I am trying to produce the following output:

> \opt\mtwilson\configuration

by using `\textbackslash{}opt \textbackslash{}mtwilson \textbackslash{}configuration`, however this outputs

> \opt \mtwilson \configuration

How do I remove the spacing?

Comment: `\textbackslash opt\textbackslash mtwilson\textbackslash configuration`, i.e. replace the `{}` by real space or try `\verb!\opt\mtwilson\configuration!`

Comment: You have spaces after `opt` and `mtwilson`: just remove them.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ??? The `{}` doesn't act like space and, indeed, that's not the source of the problem.

Comment: You could consider the `url` package and its `\path` command.

Comment: @egreg: I was thinking into wrong direction

Comment: This is a unix path isn't it ? Don't you mean slashes `/` instead of backslashes `\ `, then ?

Comment: @marsupilam Indeed. I guess I am writing too much today and start to overthink things :D Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\textbackslash opt\textbackslash mtwilson\textbackslash configuration
```

worked. Thanks @Christian Hupfer